# Auto resize img in relation to div

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem. I have images with different sizes which I would like to stretch. The height should be **40%** in relation to the **height** of the blue div element.

How can I do this? I can not work with fix sizes, because when I resize the browser the div and img element should also automatically resize.

[image]

Any idea?

Greets,
yab86

Comment: Since the height of the image depends on its width, you can't modify it if you want to preserve its original ratio. You'll have to resize the container's height to be equal to `2.5 x image height` (in this case, javascript is required), but I guess you don't want to fix the container's height... So, the question is : do you want to preserve the image's ratio?

Comment: Exactly. I would like to preserve the image's ratio. The image should be stretched. I looking for a solution without javascript. :-)

Comment: So you want to resize the DIV's height?

Comment: I mean, you can't preserve the image's ratio + have the image's width set to 100% + have the image's height to be 40% of the height of the container, without fixing the container's height using javascript.

Comment: If you want to avoid using javascript, one way could be to set the image's width to "auto" and height to "40%". Let me know.

Comment: Yes. :-) The img should have a height of 40% in relation to the blue div and the blue div should have a height of eg 20% in relation to the browser height.

Comment: I tried it with width:auto; and height: 20%. But the height of the img rest in different height-sizes. Every img have to have the same height (in relation to the blue div) and the width of the img should stretched to the 24.5%.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div{
    width: 24,5%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
div img{
    height:40%;
    max-width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
     <img src="test.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The height is 40% and the image keeps its ratio and will never exceed the width of the div.
Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks randomizer. I have to keep the div-width of 24.5%. I tried your example with a width of the blue div container of 24.5%. But nothing happen. :-(

Comment: I updated the answer. What do you mean with nothing happens? If you use my example and resize your window, the image and the div resize too.

Comment: The problem is that I have images width different sizes (eg 300px * 200px / 200px * 400px ...). The div img resize in relation to the img size.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer – it really works:

```
div{
    width: 24,5%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
$(document).ready(function(e) 
{
    $('div img').css('height',window.innerHeight);
    window.onresize = function(event) 
    {
            $('div img').css('height',window.innerHeight)
    };
});
```